# System files not hidden Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, file-attributes

I recently copied my win xp install from one hard to another(via ubuntu live cd)

Everything went well, except that all the hidden system files(boot.ini, ntdlr, io.sys) are no longer hidden.

I tried this:

attrib +s c:/IO.sys

No effect. The files are still visible even though the setting to hide system files is checked.

Any solutions? Thanks.

Comment: "System" attribute alone does not hide the file from Windows Explorer, but does hide it from "dir" command output. Like the answer stated, you should use Hidden attribute to hide it from Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the h (hidden) attribute.

```
attrib +h C:\IO.sys
```

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: In the future look at using an actual copy utility for this that will preserve attributes vs. just a graphical file manager.  That can help avoid having to fix attributes after a copy.

Comment: Yea but with ubuntu its really easy and fast you just copy the files and its done, only drawback is the file attributes. I guess if there is anything better.